# restore script in Linux part2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my other question I was having a problem with a script; though I now have the first part working. I'm also very new to Linux and scripting.

The script should ask me where I would like to restore my file to if I do `restore -n`

So if I do:

`restore -n test1.txt`

It will give me back the question

`"Where would you like to save the file?"`

I would then put for example
`/root` this will restore the file to root.

If i do `restore` it should restore the file to the original place.
So if I do:

`restore test1.txt`

It should restore it back to `/root/michael`, but when I try to restore test1.txt I get the error

```
mv: missing file operand
```

Here is what I have for my script so far, though the first part is working fine, it's the second part I'm having an issues with

```
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]
then
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  echo "Where would you like to save the file?"
  read location
  location1=`readlink -f "$location"`
  mv -i $filename "location1"/filename
else
  location=`cd /root/michael`
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore=`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  mv -i $filename "$location1" $location
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an assignment in

```
restore`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
```